# SerializationException is Unhandled Error?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, static

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 with C#.  Can anyone please tell me what:

```
Type 'bar' in Assembly 'foo, Version=5.9.0.25319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a3c4e260a36280cd' is not marked as serializable.
```

means??

Obviously I had to change the names of the classes for proprietary sake, but I'm getting this exception on a line that's similar to:

```
DisplayedData = class1.staticObject.GetShownDataList();
```

Does this have to do with the fact that I'm trying to call a method on a static instance of a class?  *Class1* is in my project, but *staticObject* holds a static instance of a class in another project that I'm referencing.

Thank you!

Comment: For type instances to cross appdomain boundaries they (the type) must be serializable or inherit from `MarshalByRefObject`.

Comment: The type of _staticObject_ does already inherit MarchalByRefObject; errors all the same.

Comment: Is DisplayedData a type or a variable name in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message means Class bar does not have the [`Serializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) attribute assigned to it. Check the link for an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is crystal clear.  Find the *bar* class in your source code and give it the [Serializable] attribute.  Do pause a minute to consider whether that deserializing an object of that class can work.

Comment: Adding [Serializable()] to the _bar_ class doesn't seem to help anything whatsoever; the exception happens exactly the same.